# Where is the output area in Atom?

Tags: python, ide, atom-editor

Total beginner here. I have just installed Atom for use as an IDE for python along with some python packages. This may seem like a very basic question, but I am unable to find the output window.

For example, I type

```
print ("Hello World")
```

and I would expect the output to be

```
Hello World
```

which is the case for any other Python compiler i can find online. However, I see "Hello World" nowhere in Atom when I run it. The only thing closest to an output would be the space below that just shows the time it took to complete running. Does python not come with an in-built output window?

I have installed packages that seemed to be what I want such as script_runner and output_panel but all to no avail. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried script package (https://atom.io/packages/script) ?

Comment: Yes I have. I have also made sure the language was set to python

Answer (score 0):

Script_runner does not work for me. I use the Script package. I go to the Packages menu item and click on the Script option in that menu. One of the options is to run the script. When I run a script this way a terminal/Console pane opens at bottom of the editor window with output written there. If you are not getting output your script may not be running.

Be sure your file name ends with .py.

Answer (score 0):

For Atom, one of the easiest ways to run python is [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run)

All you need to do is press `F5` or `F6` in the python file